# Call app.use for plugin in the component itself in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm building a component library that uses the `v-tooltip` plugin. So I need to install and use the plugin in the component itself instead using it globally with `app.use()`.
I've read so many posts, and what I've tried so far doesn't work for my case.

I know that I can access the app in the Composition API as:

```
import VTooltip from 'v-tooltip';
import 'v-tooltip/dist/v-tooltip.css';

const App = getCurrentInstance().appContext.app;
App.use(VTooltip);
```

but that doesn't work, and I get this warning:
`[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whatever is done when a plugin is added with `use`, is specific to a plugin. If you want to be sure, you need to check its source code. A lot of times it doesn't do anything outstanding and may not be needed, just adds properties globally or registers components globally. As for this lib, it's clearly for Vue 2 and not 3, end of the story.

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask for the help, I've found out how to solve this :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks @Rago, you gave me an idea with the directives. The solution was really simple in this case... At the moment `v-tooltip` is undergoing a package rename (to `floating-vue`), so with the new plugin you can decide if you want to use a component or a directive.

This is the solution:

```
<template>
...
<span v-tooltip="help" class="form-help">?</span>
...
</template>

<script>
import 'floating-vue/dist/style.css';
import { VTooltip } from 'floating-vue';

export default defineComponent({
  directives: {
    tooltip: VTooltip,
  },
  ...
});
</script>
```

And for the Composition API you just import it, and Vue will automatically detect the directive if you follow the naming convention - putting `v` in front of the directive:

```
import 'floating-vue/dist/style.css';
import { VTooltip } from 'floating-vue';

const vTooltip = VTooltip;
```

Answer (score 0):

to use this plugin in the component itself, you can try to do something like this:

```html
<template>
  <button v-tooltip="/* your code */"> Custom button </button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import VTooltip from "v-tooltip";

export default defineComponent({
  directives: {
    tooltip: VTooltip.VTooltip,
    "close-popover": VTooltip.VClosePopover,
    "v-popover": VTooltip.VPopover,
  },
});
</script>
```